# How to solve Error: Undefined name 'FileSelectorLinux'. FileSelectorLinux.registerWith(); in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to run this flutter app but its throwing this error

```
 Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_selector_linux-0.9.2/lib/file_selector_linux.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:file_selector_linux/file_selector_linux.dart';
       ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_linux-0.2.1/lib/image_picker_linux.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading '../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_selector_linux-0.9.2/lib/file_selector_linux.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:file_selector_linux/file_selector_linux.dart';
       ^
.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart:116:9: Error: Undefined name 'FileSelectorLinux'.
        FileSelectorLinux.registerWith();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_linux-0.2.1/lib/image_picker_linux.dart:20:46: Error: Method not found: 'FileSelectorLinux'.
  static FileSelectorPlatform fileSelector = FileSelectorLinux();
```

I tried solving it by adding file_selector_linux package but no use and in fact i am not using this package anywhere .How do i solve this ?